# Active Timestamps with org-add-note

Tags: org-mode

If you add a Note to a TODO task with ***C-c C-z*** it adds an inactive timestamp to the note. This way it does not show up in the agenda view.

```
- Note taken on [2019-11-05 Di 09:32] \\
```

I want ***org-add-note*** to create active Timestamps

```
- Note taken on <2019-11-05 Di 09:32> \\
```

Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize `org-log-note-headings`to change this. Using `"Note taken on %T"` instead of `"Note taken on %t"` should make the timestamps active.

Comment: Thanks that works just perfectly fine