# How to prevent agenda view from showing items' creation timestamp?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

My agenda view shows duplicated items when they are created and scheduled in the same day, which litters this view:

[image: screenshot]

So for instance The item that was created today at 11:33 will show once with its creation timestamp, and then again without timestamp. I'd like to remove the former from the view and keep the latter.

**EDIT**

Thank y'all for your help.

As @erikstokes poined out, my question was a duplicated of [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53558/active-timestamps-with-org-add-note). So the only solution I could think of is to make the timestamp inactive when capturing (creating) a note.

To this end I changed `%T` by `%U` in my capture template:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "New Task" entry (file+headline agenda-path "Inbox")
         "* TODO %?\n  %U\n  %i\n")
        )
      )
```

I also customized `org-agenda-time-grid` as suggested in the answer by @NickD, which causes timestamps to be displayed in a more compact manner, in case they are shown.

```
(setq org-agenda-time-grid
      '((require-timed)
        "----------------"
        (800 1000 1200 1400 1600 1800 2000)))
```

Comment: Yes, indeed! I'm experiencing the same problem :( Though the solution there is far from optimal. I'd rather say to org mode "don't show timestamps if it doesn't belong to a scheduled item"

Comment: Yes. See my edit ;)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to remove the time grid completely:

```
(setq org-agenda-use-time-grid nil)
```

If this variable is non-nil, then the grid is shown, but you can control (to some extent) the format of the grid entries by using the `org-agenda-time-grid` variable. The doc string for `org-agenda-time-grid` should provide some guidance on what you can do with it:

```
org-agenda-time-grid is a variable defined in ‘../org-mode/lisp/org-agenda.el’.
Its value is
((daily today require-timed)
 (800 1000 1200 1400 1600 1800 2000)
 "......" "----------------")

  You can customize this variable.

Documentation:
The settings for time grid for agenda display.
This is a list of four items.  The first item is again a list.  It contains
symbols specifying conditions when the grid should be displayed:

 daily         if the agenda shows a single day
 weekly        if the agenda shows an entire week
 today         show grid on current date, independent of daily/weekly display
 require-timed show grid only if at least one item has a time specification
 remove-match  skip grid times already present in an entry

The second item is a list of integers, indicating the times that
should have a grid line.

The third item is a string which will be placed right after the
times that have a grid line.

The fourth item is a string placed after the grid times.  This
will align with agenda items.
```

In particular, the `remove-match` setting might be what you want:

```
 (setq org-agenda-time-grid '((today remove-match) (800 1000 1200 1400 1600 1800 2000) "......" "----------------"))
```

although that keeps the entry in the grid and gets rid of the other entry.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to work. I tried `(setq org-agenda-time-grid nil)` and even some options as mentioned in the docstring, but the timestamped items keep on showing :/

Comment: Sorry - I used the wrong variable for that case. You should set `org-agenda-use-time-grid` to `nil` if you want to get rid of the time grid completely. I'll fix the answer.